# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 7

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I'm not sure why my code isn't recognizing the from_addrs | In the dict, result, it is saved as from (but this is a key word in sqlite).

Does the dict variable names from and to, need to match what is being passed in the table?

This is an example of the result dict being passed into the Table.

Example of one entry in the dict named `result` being passed in

```
 {'blockNumber': '11616713', 
 'timeStamp': '1610143998', 
 'hash': '0xbd633ba440d70d9132f17c9e34a64f9c0cb1fea014d927ae2fdcb2199de01c70', 
 'nonce': '23', 
 'blockHash': '0x5c5b750db80cf35e8fdc063503c4856824da5be440314ce9c98332f8edde33b7', 'transactionIndex': '236', 
 'from': '0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a', 
 'to': '0xd26114cd6ee289accf82350c8d8487fedb8a0c07', 
 'value': '0',
 'gas': '52346', 
 'gasPrice': '90000000000', 
 'isError': '0', 
 'txreceipt_status': '1', 
 'input': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000c88fe66bcc71cf840c6a9aae4892c07a38b9e6260000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a69671228c57640000', 
 'contractAddress': '', 
 'cumulativeGasUsed': '10008235', 
 'gasUsed': '52346', 
 'confirmations': '3314384'}]
```

code:

```
 # Create table

 c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE rndTable (
     blockNumber INTEGER,
     timeStamp INTEGER,
     hash BLOB,
     nonce INTEGER,
     blockHash BLOB,
     transactionIndex INTEGER,
     from_addrs BLOB,
     to_addrs BLOB,
     value INTEGER,
     gas INTEGER,
     gasPrice INTEGER,
     isError INTEGER,
     txreceipt_status INTEGER,
     input BLOB,
     contractAddress BLOB,
     cumulativeGasUsed INTEGER,
     gasUsed INTEGER,
     confirmation INTEGER
  ); ''')


# Insert into the database
c.executemany('INSERT INTO rndTable VALUES (:blockNumber,:timeStamp,:hash,:nonce,:blockHash,:transactionIndex,:from_addrs,:to_addrs,:value,:gas,:gasPrice,:isError,:txreceipt_status,:input,:contractAddress,:cumulativeGasUsed,:gasUsed,:confirmation)', result)

# To commit the inserted lines to the database
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you @buran for editing my question to make it more legible - how did you do that?

Comment: Regarding editing - check https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The placeholders must match the keys in the dictionary, so you want `:from`  and `:to` not `from_addrs` and `to_addrs`.

Comment: Yeah, only issue is "from" is a key word for sql - that's why I ended up relabelling it as from_addrs